# How to replace equal sign in batch script

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I want to replace `<Context useHttpOnly="false">` with `<Context>`

```
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%A in ( %INTEXTFILE%) do (
SET string=%%A
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
SET modified=!string:^<Context useHttpOnly^="false"^>=^<Context!
echo !modified! >> %OUTTEXTFILE%
endlocal
)
```

Output: nothing change.

Problem found because of equal sign and double quotes.

Comment: Batch is awful for this kind of stuff in my opinion. You could use something like this: http://www.seabreezecomputers.com/htmlstripper/ to strip attributes. Just put in which tags you want to keep and which attributes and press submit. I guess this wont work if this is something you have to do man times.

Comment: Batch is a major hassle when working with string manipulation and special characters.  It can be done, but not without limitations.  Highly recommend you use some other script language such as JScript/VBScript or PowerShell if you want to perform string manipulation.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/8591185/891976

Answer (score 2):

```
@echo off
SET "string=<Context useHttpOnly="false">"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo String: !string!
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims==>" %%i in ("!string!") do (
   if "%%i" equ "<Context useHttpOnly" if "%%~j" equ "false" set "modified=<Context>"
)
echo Modified: !modified!
```

Comment: I have tried it but it is not working. I have written it in separate bat file and run but not success. Actually I have to replace this <Context useHttpOnly="false"> string in xml file.. So I have to find it in xml file and replace it...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a helper batch file called repl.bat - http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3855

This command may work for you...

```
type file.txt|repl "<Context.*.false.>" "<Context>" >newfile.txt
```